# How important are the initial values for non linear optimization?

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system, numerical-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Based on what I understand, non-linear optimization can only find the closest local minimum based on the initial values given. Therefore, the initial values are very important, because if the initial values are close enough to the global minimum, the closest local minimum found by the non-linear optimizer will have a high chance to be the desired global minimum.

However, recently I came across a few CVPR papers that clearly stated their problem is non-convex, and solved their problem via non-linear optimization. However, according to the author, the initial values are zero initialized and are obviously far away from the actual solution, but yet they were able to showcase phenomenal results that are better than the state of the art, and they didn't bother to explain why zero initialization works for their problem in the paper.

Can someone let me know whether there's something wrong with my understanding of the concept of non-linear optimization?

Comment: Maybe it would be useful if you could link to one of these papers.

Comment: It heavily depends on optimization method and model. I don't think any of them actually guarantees arriving to "closest" local minimum, but yes, in general they can't guarantee global minimum. However, for example, for many types of neural network it is either theoretically or empirically established that most local minimums are not much  worse than global.

Comment: @garondal Here is the paper I am referring to: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.05131.pdf

Comment: @mihaild From my understanding, if the problem is non-linear least squares, classical methods like LM will converge to the closest local minimum. There isn't a mechanism for LM to escape out of the local minimum.

Comment: @user3667089 it can converge to some other minimum (it can be converge to closest, but it is not guaranteed).

Comment: @mihaild do you mind giving a toy example to demonstrate a scenario that it wouldn't converge to the closest? Also, based on what you said, if having initial values closer to the global minimum doesn't mean there's a higher chance of converging to it, then what should be the principle for picking initial values for non-linear optimization?

Comment: @user3667089 take any function, apply LM to any function - it will look at finite number of points. Then slightly modify function very close to initial point to make there a new local minima.

Comment: Taking initialization closer to global minimum helps, but isn't absolutely necessary for finding good solution. How exactly choose it - is open question and active research area.